# Guest OS Ubuntu 12.04 no network connection

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox

Recently added a new `*.VDI` image with Ubuntu 12.04 to my existing VirtualBox. The machine hangs with a "Waiting for network configuration" error, eventually times out after 60 seconds and boots in command line mode. How can I activate the GUI mode for this machine?

Some useful information:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet dhcp

ip link 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> ..
2: eth1: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST> ..
```

I tried to use the below command:

```
ifup eth0
```

it fails with following error message:

```
cannot find device "eth0" Failed to bring up eth0
```

`ifconfig` didn't show any `eth*` and I am confused now. Can anyone help?

Comment: What network card does VBox emulate? The default is an Intel, which is supported by Linux/BSD/Solaris, I can testify for that. Try 'ifconfig -a'.

Comment: That useful info, is that from the guest or the host? that isn't clear to me

Comment: It shows an eth1, and you try to configure eth0....

Comment: @schaiba: `ifconfig -a` gives **eth1 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 08:00:27:ee:25:3d** and **lo Link encap:Local Loopback** just included the first line from the display. This is from guest os.

Comment: @vonbrand: yes, but I am not able to get `ping www.unix.stackexchange.com` fron the machine.

Comment: ping -I eth1 www.google.com

Comment: @schaiba: gives ping: unknown host www.google.com

Comment: What's in /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: @schaiba: Seems an empty file! also when I checked `route` which displays an empty routing table. Any clue what is going wrong? Thanks so much.

Comment: also `cat /etc/network/run/ifstate` gives only **lo=lo**

Comment: Take a look here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40510/cannot-connect-to-my-virtual-box-ubuntu-system

Answer (score 1):

So you have a local VirtualBox install of Ubuntu 12.04 that doesn’t see a network connection? And I am assuming you want it to reach the outside world, correct? Have you checked your main network settings for the virtual machine in VirtualBox itself?

I setup my VirtualBox similarly to what is explained on [Christopher Maier’s post here](http://christophermaier.name/blog/2010/09/01/host-only-networking-with-virtualbox) and it works great.

The key is to setup two adapters. The first adapter is `Adapter 1` and that is set to NAT. And `Adapter 2` to be a host-only adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Check the content of `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file to get the names assigned to your network devices by `udev`. Usually, those should be `eth0` for wired and `wlan0` for wireless, but not necessarily. Then put the appropriate names into the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Answer (score 0):

At least once, after *Add*-ing a premade `.vbox` to VirtualBox, I encountered this error because... in `Settings > Network - Advanced` the `Cable Connected` option had apparently not been left as checked upon having been *Add*-ed. Why? Who knows. I would say that most of the time, however, it will be because of udev rules & the like.